The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API
I have an API, which when tested on my localhost works fine, but on the server, when I call it in the published one, I get the error:

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

In inner exception:

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:  Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): Mensaje recibido inesperado, o bien su formato es incorrecto.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The code in the controller is:
[HttpGet]
[Route("obtienerespuesta")]
public async Task<List<ResponsePymeModels>> InboundTransfersItauPyme(string api_key, string AccountLink, string AccountNumber, string urlbanco, string BookingDate)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    Configuere(serviceCollection);

    var servicios = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    var httpClientFactory = servicios.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

    var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(230);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", api_key);

    var json = new JObject(
                     new JProperty("RequestData",
                         new JObject(
                             new JProperty("AccountCredential",
                                 new JObject(
                                     new JProperty("AccountLink", AccountLink)
                                 )
                             ),
                             new JProperty("AccountNumber", AccountNumber),
                             new JProperty("BookingDate", BookingDate),
                             new JProperty("Currency", "CLP")
                                 )
                             )
                 );

    var postData = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var request = await client.PostAsync(urlbanco, postData);//aki se cae
    var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // ..........
    // ..........
}

private static void Configuere(ServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
}

It falls into the PostAsync line. I would like if someone could help me or indicate how to solve it.

You could use network tools such as wireshark to observe at which step the handshake fails. Sometimes it is because missmatch tls version or cipher.
